# Why can't I set my time zone to UTC?

Tags: twitter

I prefer to set some of my web applications to UTC so as to make things less confusing when I travel. However, I've been having trouble setting my Twitter's time zone to UTC:

1. I noticed when looking at settings that the time zone had been set to `(GMT -11) International Date Line West`.
2. Convinced that this had been made in error -- that this must have simply resulted from accidentally pressing the `HOME` or `PgUp` buttons while still on the menu, or from failing to actually save changes, I set the time zone back to `(GMT) UTC`, clicked `Save changes`, and entered in the correct password. After being redirected to the updated settings page (or after refreshing the page), I notice that my time zone is back to `(GMT -11)`.
3. I then tried testing a few other time zones, including the other ones listed as `GMT`. I don't run into any issues when I change my time zone to those. (I would rather not use the other GMT options, since I can't tell if those would affect any of my other settings.)

Is it simply impossible to set one's time zone to UTC on Twitter, or is this just some bug? (If so, this would make for some pretty poor UX, as far as I'm concerned.)

Comment: I'm getting the exact same issue.